# Hi guys!...can i write subscriber and publisher for an application like Blender-Ros-Blender?

Tags: ros, blender

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example i have an animation of a moving box on blender and  i just wanted control the speed of the moving box using Ros subscriber and publisher, like one blender window as publisher and another blender window as subscriber,so that i can see the change in velocity on the subscriber blender window? thanks!

---

Update:
Thanks allenh1 for the response!! I know a little bit about MORSE. what i am looking for is to check weather there is a way that i can run blender as two different nodes in ROS ,using rosrun? or if am not mistaken is there a way to have ROS Package for blender? am sorry if am confusing,am not an expert in this area, please your help,thanks a lot!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182409/hi-guys!...can-i-write-subscriber-and-publisher-for-an-application-like-blender-ros-blender?/) by [Alazar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19380/alazar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for here... There is some blender implementation out there, though. Look into a project called MORSE. It has lots of ROS tools with it, and has relatively good documentation.

---

I'm not seeing why you need two blender windows... You can have a program act as both a publisher and subscriber. I am still not exactly sure what you want to do here... Could you please state explicitly what each blender window would do?

e.g.

Window 1:

- Things happen

Window 2:

- Different things happen

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alazar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19380/alazar/) on 2014-07-10**:
Am not sure it is logical or not , but what am looking for is:-
window1
- i have certain animation
- want to publish change in some parameters of the animation, say the speed
- subscribe the change in animation, see the effect in the same window.,then
Window 2
- i have the same animation as window 1
-want to subscribe the change in speed published in window 1 , and see the same change in
animation  same as window 1....so that ideally i can use blender both as animation and simulation tool.
thanks!